# Parse JSONObject from Tumblr

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, tumblr

I'm trying to teach myself to make android apps, therefore i'm trying to create an app that shows images from an tumblr account in an list view.

I have some problem parsing the JSONObject and my app crashes because of an nullPointerException.

My code looks like this:

```
public class Example extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;
    try {
        tweets = getTweets();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewId);
        listView.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem,
                tweets));
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {
    private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int imageViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Tweet> tweets) {
        super(context, imageViewResourceId, tweets);
        this.tweets = tweets;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
        if (tweet != null) {

            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);

            if (image != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(tweet.image_url));
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                .getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets() throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, JSONException {
    String searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/www.richkidsofinstagram.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY";

    ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    String responseBody = null;
    try {
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

    JSONArray arr = null;

    try {
        arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.v("TEST", "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("photos"));
        tweets.add(tweet);
    }

    return tweets;
}

public class Tweet {

    public String image_url;

    public Tweet(String url) {

        this.image_url = url;
    }
    }
    }
```

The nullPointerException occurs at line 124:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("photos"));
        tweets.add(tweet);
    }
```

Also i have validated the address via www.jsonlint.com and the JSON looks like this:

```
{
"meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK"
},
"response": {
    "blog": {
        "title": "Rich Kids Of Instagram",
        "posts": 154,
        "name": "richkidsofinstagram",
        "url": "http://richkidsofinstagram.tumblr.com/",
        "updated": 1346803265,
        "description": "They have more money than you and this is what they do.
        "ask": true,
        "ask_anon": true
    },
    "posts": [
        {
            "blog_name": "richkidsofinstagram",
            "id": 30900248446,
            "post_url":          "http://richkidsofinstagram.tumblr.com/post/30900248446/hamptons-are-good",
            "slug": "hamptons-are-good",
            "type": "photo",
            "date": "2012-09-04 23:58:45 GMT",
            "timestamp": 1346803125,
            "state": "published",
            "format": "html",
            "reblog_key": "2KosMjea",
            "tags": [
                "pool",
                "hamptons",
                "summer",
                "rich",
                "wealth"
            ],
            "highlighted": [],
            "note_count": 99,
            "caption": "<p><span>The Hamptons are…….. good. by matthewmorton</span></p>",
            "photos": [
                {
                    "caption": "",
                    "alt_sizes": [
                        {
                            "width": 500,
                            "height": 500,
                            "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9uiqy9Mi71rb86ldo1_500.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "width": 400,
                            "height": 400,
                            "url": "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9uiqy9Mi71rb86ldo1_400.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "width": 250,
                            "height": 250,
                            "url": "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9uiqy9Mi71rb86ldo1_250.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "width": 100,
                            "height": 100,
                            "url": "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9uiqy9Mi71rb86ldo1_100.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "width": 75,
                            "height": 75,
                            "url": "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9uiqy9Mi71rb86ldo1_75sq.jpg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "original_size": {
                        "width": 500,
                        "height": 500,
                        "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9uiqy9Mi71rb86ldo1_500.jpg"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

I think the problem is that i don't specify which picture size i want or something like that, but i have no clue how to solve the problem.

If anyone could help me solve this problem it would be highly appriciated.

Comment: Two points need to discuss, first : your json don't have results tag from which your fetch your json array, second : your photos tag has json object's array not a json

Comment: Thanks for helping. Instead og results it should say "posts" as i want to fetch the images. But then when "photos" also is an array, how should i set this up i my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note sure which line exactly is 124, copy and pasted your code and only ended up with ~115 lines total? Anyway here goes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
```

That should normally be fine since the call to set `arr` should throw a `JSONException` exception if there is no array named "results".  You eat that exception though, and just log it, which could leave `arr` as `null`.  Also, I don't see any "results" in your JSON, did you mean "response"?  That is my guess if you are getting a `NullPointerException`.

Could stop reading here if you want, but going to explain why I'm guessing the next 2 lines aren't 124 / aren't the one throwing the exception:

```
Tweet tweet = new Tweet(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("photos"));
```

That looks safe becuase if arr isn't null `getJSONObject()` should return something for your `i` values. And `getString()` would throw a `JSONException` if it couldn't find "photos".  (I'm not sure what that `Tweet` class is exactly, so if "photos" returned null and the `Tweet` constructer died on a null argument, well that could be it, but I don't know...)

```
tweets.add(tweet);
```

This looks safe too because you initialized `tweets` as `new ArrayList<Tweet>();` and even if `tweet` was null, an `ArrayList()` won't have a problem with that.

Comment: Oh thanks alot for helping me.
Line 124 is this: for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
What really is the big mistake is that it says "results" as the Array tag. 
If i want a photo shouldn't the Array tag be posts?
But then because Photos also is an array how does i handle this if i want to get the highst qulaty?